# python pkg_resources does not seem to respect sys.path

Tags: python, sys.path, pkg-resources

I'm using Python 2.7 and trying to run

```
pkg_resources.get_distribution(appname).version
```

over multiple apps.

I thought I would be able to do this by manipulating sys.path within the program but it doesn't seem to be recognized by pkg_resources; I can only get an app to be recognized when launching the script from the particular 'appname' directory.

I can make this work in a clunky way with two separate programs, one which jumps around in the file hierarchy and then calls the other to actually run the command above. But this seems ridiculous ...

Anybody have insight into this? Is this a bug in pkg_resources or something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe you import pkg_resources too early. It has a default state object that is initialized on import, so any change to sys.path later doesn't do anything (unless you tell pkg_resources).

Comment: Thanks I'll try importing later!

Comment: Schlenk's fix worked!